# norms are not equivalent - proof

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

Consider the sequence of functions $f_n : [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$ given by

$$ f_n(x) =
\begin{cases}
    1 - nx &0 \le x \le 1/n\;\\
                1& \textrm{otherwise}\;\;,
\end{cases}
$$

for $n > 0$, which converges pointwise to $f(x) = 1$ as $n \to \infty$. 
Show that $f_n$ does not converge to $f$ in the uniform norm, but it does converge using the inner product norm as given below
$$||f||_2 = \left({\int |f(x)|^2 dx}\right)^{1/2}$$

Any help with this question is appreciated. I understand its related to infinite dimensional vector spaces, there are norms that are not equivalent. I dont know how to proceed with the proof.

Comment: What did you try? Try computing $f_n(\frac{1}{n})$ and see if it helps you prove that the convergence is not uniform. And did you compute the integral?

Comment: I tried computing the integral, by spliting it into two parts as per the given interval, i got infinity as answer, do i need to ignore the 1 , Otherwise part?

Comment: @Art then you should include this in your post. You should always include any of your own attempts to solve the problem when asking a question.

Comment: $\int_{0}^{1} |f_n(x)|^2 dx=\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{n}}(1-nx)^2 dx+\int_{\frac{1}{n}}^{1} 1 dx $ is not infinity and neither is $\int_{0}^{1} |f_n(x)-f(x)|^2 dx$

Comment: @Paul thank you, i did mistake in the limit of second integral, i integrated from 1/n to infinity.

Comment: @Plop Thank you. I did it using your hint.